# Tor will not setup on Raspberry Pi. Is it compatible with FireFox ESR?

Tags: tor-install

Ok so I have Tor downloaded, but I try to open the Setup program. It doesn't open. I also have another Tor downloaded that is installed, but I can't open it either. I think it has to do with the fact that it can't run on Firefox ESR. What is the problem?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to run Tor Browser on a Raspberry Pi? I don't think you can do that. The ARM CPUs used by the Rasperry Pis aren't supported as far as I know.